# YouTube Android Player API stopped working suddenly

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

My app uses this version `YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.2.2.zip` https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads

Recently my users started to report issues that videos aren't being played/loading - endless circle progress bar.

I checked on my Samsung S10 (Android 12) and it also has the same issue.

But I checked on pixel emulator (also Android 12) and it works fine, I even updated YouTube app to the latest version and still it works, so weird.

So emulator and real device has same version of YouTube app (17.22.36) and both on Android 12 but it doesn't work for real device only

And mb it effects only some users. App has enough users but only a few report this problem now and it doesn't work for my real device

Comment: We are facing the same problem. We log the `YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason` on our analytics service and we have noticed an increase of `UNEXPECTED_SERVICE_DISCONNECTION`. Maybe youtube app is crashing on background

Comment: There is a major bug with the YouTube Player API, affecting the latest YouTube version 17.22.36 on Android. Google are aware of the bug. You can click +1 on the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/235704583

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem .
My YouTube App has some users and it works fine several years .

After update android12.
My app not works .

Debug point is just : youtube fragmentX(override) - OnStart() , and endless circle progress bar.

No problem in other version real phones (Samsung S10) .
I thougth that 'Restrictions on background starts' realated bug on android12 .

-->
https://www.getdroidtips.com/netflix-youtube-not-working-after-update/

I just clear YouTube Cash, and Data.
And it works again ..

Comment: yes, clearing the data of YouTube app solves the issue